# Is the linear map onto.

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional real vector space and let $f$ and $g$ be non-zero  linear functionals on $V$. Assume that $\ker(f) \subset \ker(g)$. Which of the following is true?

1. $\ker(f) = \ker(g)$
2. $f=cg$ for some real non-zero number c
3. The linear map $A:V\to \mathbb{R}^2$ defined by

$Ax=(f(x),g(x))$ for all $x\in V$, is onto.

I know first and second are true. How to solve third? I think it is false.

Answer (score 1):

If you pick $f=g$, then clearly the image of $A$ is the line $\{ (x,x) : x  \in \mathbb{R} \}$, so it is not onto.

Comment: @egreg actually he gave another answer before (which he has edited), in which he gave a counter-example to 1) and 2)...that's why i asked him. since he has removed that answer, so i'll remove my comment as well.

Answer (score 0):

Since $ker\ f=ker\ $ and dim $ker\ f$ = $n-1$ (assuming $V$ to be $n$-dimensional) implies dim $ker\ A$ = $n-1$ and hence by Rank-Nullity Theorem, the rank is $1$
 and hence the map is not onto.

Answer (score 0):

The first and second are true.

The third is false.  You could use the same example.  In general, the image of this function will be the span of $(f(x),g(x))$ with $x \notin \ker(f) \cup \ker(g)$.

The first and second can be proven with a careful application of the rank-nullity theorem.

Comment: Dear @omnonmn why 1 is not true? I think it's true

Comment: See the example I gave: $f \neq g$, but $\ker f = \ker g$.

Comment: thanks first of all. first statement says that ker(f) =ker(g). it does not say if f is not equal to g then ker(f)may be equal to ker(g). Please see the proof given below by wanderer. I think it is true. Please check it once.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I misread the question.  Yes, you're right: we do have $\ker f = \ker g$.  Wanderer's proof is fine.